# Is there a way to create a function that creates a new variable with the name of one of the parameters?

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying to create a very rudimentary system for storing player stats and want to create a table where I can enter a parameter for the table's variable name. I am very new to lua and am unsure about if it's possible.

I made a basic outline that I wanted to expand upon but made this for testing purposes

```
local function Info(playerInfo,health,energy,speed,attack,physicalDefense,magicalDefense)
    playerInfo = {
        health = health,
        energy = energy,
        speed = speed,
        attack = attack,
        physicalDefense = physicalDefense, 
        magicalDefense = magicalDefense, 
    }
    return playerInfo
end
Info(playerName,[rest of the stats])
```

Is there a way to make it so that if i used the argument "playerName" for playerInfo the table is given the identifier "playerName" so I can make unique tables for different characters? I want to be able to reference the info within the table such as playerName.health for example but another character may have characterName.health. Essentially, I'm looking for a way to optimize how much I need to type for each character.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a table key/index dynamically using brackets, e.g.:

```lua
players[playerName] = ...
```

In your case, you are trying to modify what is called the [global environment](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#2.2), which you can access with `_G`.

However, it is highly non-recommended to dump values into that global environment. Aside from accidentally overwriting existing values, its simply not the place to keep player data.

Make a separate table for your players, and put them there like in my code block and access them as e.g., `players.someSpecificName.health`, or more dynamically `players[playerName].health`. Beware nil players.